# My game is not showing in Google play store in "New Game Releases"

Tags: android, google-play

I've made an android game and published in play.google.com yesterday, but my game is not showing in  the "New + Updated Games"  or the "New Game Releases" category of google play store... Why ? 
this is my game playstore link :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mahdi.heydarzadeh.turbotire

Comment: Why not [ask google themselves](http://developer.android.com/support.html)?

Comment: ok i will ask .. tanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, on the internet you have to give things some "time" and they sort themselves out. If in a day or so it still doesn't show up, then you might need to contact Google directly.

Comment: i know but my game is published and showing but i want my game show in New Game Releases or ... because i want people see my game.. sorry for my bad english...

Comment: yeah, it might take some time to show in the new releases section. Google deals with a lot of data. Just wait and see, and if it still doesn't show up then contact someone about it.

Comment: ok you right .. i will waiting .. tanx

Comment: and in the mean time, do some extra research and make sure there aren't any special requirements, etc. for getting in that section.